# pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosedByBroker: (320, 'CONNECTION_FORCED - Node was put into maintenance mode')

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I was getting this exception in production environment.

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosedByBroker: (320, 'CONNECTION_FORCED - Node was put into maintenance mode')
```

currently I don't have any idea to fixing this exception. I was unable to reproduce in Realtime.

consumer.py

```
class MessageQConsumer:
    """

    """

    def __init__(
            self,
            config: ConfigReader,
            exchange_name: str,
            queue_name: str,
            topic: str
    ):
        self.config = config
        self.logger = LoggerHandler(self.config).logger
        self.publisher = None

        # exchange name
        self.exchange_name = exchange_name
        self.queue_name = queue_name

        self.connection = get_connection()

        # mq channel
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        # limit prefetch with a single message, no sense to take more requests from the queue
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

        # configuration of the exchange
        self.channel.exchange_declare(
            exchange=self.exchange_name, exchange_type=MessageQExchangesTypes.TOPIC,
            durable='true'
        )

        # declare queue
        temp = self.channel.queue_declare(self.queue_name, durable='true')
        self.queue = temp.method.queue

        # bind routing key in queue
        self.channel.queue_bind(
            exchange=self.exchange_name, queue=self.queue, routing_key=topic
        )

        # list of threads
        self.threads = []

        # retry_count
        self.retry_count = 1

    def run(self) -> None:
        """

        """
        try:
            on_message_callback = functools.partial(
                self.on_message, args=(self.connection, self.threads))
            self.channel.basic_consume(
                queue=self.queue, on_message_callback=on_message_callback)
            self.channel.start_consuming()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.channel.stop_consuming()

        # Wait for all to complete.
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()

        # connection close.
        self.connection.close()

    def on_message(self, channel, method, properties, body, args) -> None:
        """

        """
        (connection, threads) = args
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work, args=(
            connection, method, channel, body, properties))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    def do_work(self, connection, method, channel, body, properties) -> None:
        """

        """
        self.message_queue_handle_request(body, properties)
        channel_connection = functools.partial(self.ack_message, channel, method)
        connection.add_callback_threadsafe(channel_connection)

    def ack_message(self, channel, method) -> None:
        """

        """
        if channel.is_open:
            channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)
        else:
            self.logger.error(f"RabbitMq channel is closed !!")
            # Channel is already closed, so we can't ACK this message;

    def message_queue_handle_request(self, body, properties) -> None:
        """
        
        """
        data = {}
        self.logger.info(f"Initialize the Message Publisher")
        if not self.publisher:
            self.publisher = MessageQPublisher(
                self.config,
                self.exchange_name
            )

        try:
            # process internal algorithm
            pass
        except Exception as exception:
            pass
```

publisher.py

```
class MessageQPublisher:
    """
    
    """

    def __init__(self, config: ConfigReader, exchange: str):
        self.config = config
        self.logger = LoggerHandler(self.config).logger
        self.exchange = exchange

    def publish(self, routing_key: str, body: str, header_retry_count=None) -> None:
        """
        
        """
        headers_value = {'retryCount': header_retry_count} if header_retry_count else {}

        # connection
        connection = get_connection(self.config)

        # setup channel
        channel = connection.channel()

        # declare the exchange that should be used
        channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.exchange,
                                 exchange_type=MessageQExchangesTypes.TOPIC,
                                 durable='true')
        channel.basic_publish(
            self.exchange,
            routing_key,
            body.encode('utf8'),
            properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                # make message persistent
                delivery_mode=2,
                expiration='3600000',
                headers=headers_value
            )
        )
```

connection.py

```
def get_connection(config_data=config):
    """
    

    """
    if config_data.mb_protocol == MessageQProtocol.AMQPS:
        ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        return pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host=config_data.mb_ip,
                port=config_data.mb_port,
                credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(
                    config_data.mb_user,
                    config_data.mb_password
                ),
                heartbeat=600,
                blocked_connection_timeout=300,
                ssl_options=pika.SSLOptions(context=ssl_context)))
    else:
        return pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host=config_data.mb_ip,
                port=config_data.mb_port,
                credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(
                    config_data.mb_user,
                    config_data.mb_password),
                heartbeat=600,
                blocked_connection_timeout=300)
        )
```

The above mentioned coding is currently running in our environment.

The pod was restarting sometimes with this exception.

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosedByBroker: (320, 'CONNECTION_FORCED - Node was put into maintenance mode')
```

I was following this tutorial

link : https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/d896d4e34ba410bca5b730d17c76d94aae484a4e/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py#L33